# .NET syntax of responsestring to match JS-callback function with multiple parameter

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, http

i would like to pass multiple parameters in my callback function and don't know who to do this...

This would be the C# code:

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        Response.Write("content of param1");
        Response.Write("content of param2");
        Response.End();
```

and the JS code:

```
    $.getJSON("localhost/myFunction", dataString,
        function(param1, param2) {
           alert(param1);
           alert(param2);
        });
```

How would i perform the actual mapping of parameter in the C# code, so JavaScript recognizes them as the 2 parameters of the callback function? ( In detail i want to pass a JSON-object and a "status" parameter here... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a proper way to do this, and I'm sure you'll find it quite convenient, so I'll show you that instead of hacking away at what you've got to make it work:

Create a webservice file (asmx) in your website. In the cs (or vb) file that's created, just above the class declaration, there's a `ScriptService` attribute that's commented out. Uncomment it, so that you can access the service from script.

Create a new method that returns the values in an object (anonymous types will do). Note the `WebMethod` attribute:

```
[WebMethod]
public object MyFunction() {
    return new {
        status = "Status string",
        jsobj = new {
            childParam = "complex object",
            childArray = new[] { "holds", "any", "values", "convertible", "to", "js" }
        }
    };
}
```

You can now make an AJAX call to this method, from your code, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'MyService.asmx/MyFunction',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: '{}',
    success: function(res) {
        alert(res.status);
        alert(res.jsobj.childParam);
    }
});
```

This way, .NET will take care of the JSON serialization for you, and you won't have to worry about escaping characters within your return values etc.

Answer (score 0):

Send the parameters as a JSON encoded object:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Response.Write("{ param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2' }");
```

And in javascript:

```
$.getJSON('localhost/myFunction', dataString,
    function(json) {
        alert(json.param1);
        alert(json.param2);
});
```

Comment: no, one parameter should be of type "string" and the other of type "json"... the "string" parameter should indicate if the json object is "valid" or not

Comment: If the JSON sent by the server is not valid it won't even call the success callback. You could also construct an object like this: `{ param1: 'valid', param2: { p1: 'foo', p2: 'bar' } }`

Comment: @David: i don't think you've understood the response. The values of the parameters would not have to be strings, although they are in your example. the anonymous callback function you're passing to `getJSON` is being called *by* the `getJSON` function, and no amount of tampering with your response will affect how many parameters `getJSON` will pass to your callback.